# How can I research UK parties' Mental Health policies before I vote?

Tags: united-kingdom, healthcare

The mainstream media is reporting about the key issues prior to the general election on May 7th here in the UK. Key issues include Law & Order, Education, Immigration etc.

But what about other specific issues? How would someone who relies on Mental Health Services (or would if they were better funded and organized) find out about what the parties are saying about this specific issue?

Labour's manifesto contains a few mentions such as :

> Labour will give mental health the same priority as physical health, with a new
>   right to access talking therapies
>
> We will increase the proportion of the mental health budget that is
>   spent on children

It could be argued that basing one's vote on such a specific service would be both selfish and misguided but is there somewhere I can find out more detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my very helpful Uncle (a former politics lecturer / teacher) :

It's pretty clear that the Lib Dems are the only party seriously to prioritise mental health issues but their promise of £3.5bn (£0.7bn pa) extra is actually way less than 1% total NHS spending but maybe still significant.

This came out pre-election but seems have been [referenced](http://www.theguardian.com/society/christmas-charity-appeal-2014-blog/2014/dec/10/-sp-mental-health-manifesto-five-things-that-need-to-change) by Lib Dems and others

1. [Liberal Democrats](http://www.libdems.org.uk/liberal-democrats-plan-to-invest-3-5bn-in-mental-health)
2. [Conservative](http://news.liv.ac.uk/2015/04/15/viewpoint-the-conservative-partys-election-manifesto-and-mental-health-rights/)
3. [Labour](https://www.mentalhealthtoday.co.uk/labour-make-manifesto-commitments-to-improve-mental-health-services.aspx)

Greens have some mentions but not very specific.

[Kings Fund](http://election.kingsfund.org.uk/) often quite good

Answer (score 2):

For a very brief overview, news websites may provide a summary (e.g. [this one from the BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-29642613), as well as their even more concise [manifesto guide](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/election/2015/manifesto-guide)).

However, if more detail is needed, the best place to look is each party's manifesto, all of which have now been published, and are freely available on the web.